# Is it good practice to use non interrupting intermediate message catch event on boundary of receive task in camunda

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

[image]

**Why I did this:**

The reason to use this kind of approach is because I want the workflow to wait at this node until the video gets completely copied, but at the same time I want to get notified about the % of progress made while copying that will be sent from a different application at every 2s.

**Problem faced:**

At random while executing the workflow the intermediate message catch event on the boundary does not get registered and I get error mostly for the first callback from video copy application when it tries to correlate the message event on the boundary.

Their are others ways also like making a simple Loop in camunda to achieve the same behavior
[image]

But the random error in my case is my concern if any one knows about same issue or if anyone with a better approach can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The approach with the non-interrupted boundary event is valid, but maybe a bit verbose. I would prefer it over any loop construct, but have you also thought about "just" updating a process variable from the outside to indicate the status? You do not need any BPMN element to allow this. See for example the REST API on update of process variables: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/reference/rest/process-instance/variables/put-variable/. The same is of course possible with Java API.

> At random while executing the workflow the intermediate message catch event on the boundary does not get registered and I get error mostly for the first callback from video copy application when it tries to correlate the message event on the boundary.

This should not happen and must have some reason which you should try to figure out. Receiving message events work 100% in Camunda itself, so you should search for a hint when this occurs, or best extract a small test case to isolate the problem.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I came across this post in camunda forum [message-correlation-exception-in-receive-task](https://forum.camunda.org/t/message-correlation-exception-in-receive-task/4560/8) this also explains a similar kind of problem and have some suggestions to solve it. I will try out those suggestions also and will check which is better to use.